# UIAlertController title and message not displaying in iphone 12

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, xcode13

I displayed UIAlertController with UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet style. When building with XCode 13 UIAlertController title and message not working on iPhone 12. It's working on other devices. Same code previously working on iPhone 12.

```
-(void)alertSheetUI{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Static Title" message:@"Static Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    
    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Data 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    }]];
    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Data 2" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    }]];
    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Data 3" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    }]];
    
    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        }];
    }]];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController presentViewController:actionSheet animated:NO completion:nil];
});}
```

**iPhone 12**

[image]

**iPhone SE**
[image]

View hierarchy shows title and message as white color. So only the title and message are not visible. I try to set the title and message as green Using attributed text using the below code. But the title and message color are not updated on other devices also. Other devices displayed as grey.

**Updated Code**

```
-(void)alertSheetUI{

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSString * string = @"Static Title";
        NSMutableAttributedString * attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Static Title"];
        [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                 value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
        UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Static Title" message:@"Static Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
        [actionSheet setValue:attrString forKey:@"attributedTitle"];
        [actionSheet setValue:attrString forKey:@"attributedMessage"];

        [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Data 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        }]];
        [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Data 2" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        }]];
        [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Data 3" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        }]];

        [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

            [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            }];
        }]];
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController presentViewController:actionSheet animated:NO completion:nil];
    });}
```

[image]

Comment: try with  simulator once

Comment: what's the system version of the running device? the pic seems that you have customize the appearance of the UIAlertController?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik working fine on iPhone 12 simulator

Comment: @childrenOurFuture Device version is iOS 15. I do not customize UIAlertController UI. It looks like this is only on iPhone 12 using mentioned code.  iPhone SE Screen shoot added for reference.

Comment: Tint color/UIAppearance customization done? The text seems "white" on white background, so invisible. If you check (with debug view hierarchy for instance), the text is present, right?

Comment: @Larme I tried to set attributed text with a different color at that time also the title is not displaying. I don’t have a testing  device iPhone 12 so unable to check view hierarchy

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik previously I am checking Sample app code that working fine in the simulator. Our project code creates issues on the simulator also. Question updated

Comment: @Larme view hierarchy updated

Comment: So the text is correctly set and present. The issue is its color. As said previously, did you changed tintColor for your UIViewController?

Comment: @Larme ViewController tint color not changed

Comment: @Ranjani - when you called this `alertSheetUI` on viewload or any button action

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik called in button action

Answer (score 0):

Your code does ask the uiapplication to display the alert . You may try to use :

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:actionShert animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

The main async queue is only needed when showing or presenting the alert.

Comment: screen created inside the library. I don't have a self-object.  So your answer not working on my scenario